# a conjunctive normal form that is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

Are there any examples of CNF formulas that are tautologies?
Such that every clause contains different variables so phrases like (a or not a) are rejected?

Comment: A CNF formula cannot be a tautology unless a variable and its negation are in the same clause.  The proof of the existence of a non-satisfying assignment for a formula lacking such a clause is simple: Clauses forbid assignments, so take any clause and assign its variables so that they match the clause's forbidden assignment.

Comment: The empty CNF works.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What is the empty CNF?

Comment: The CNF with zero terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any clause in the formula. If all variables in that clause are different, we can always assign $0$ to a non-negated variable and $1$ to a negated variable. This makes that clause $0$. Therefore, it makes the CNF formula $0$. Thus, tautology is not possible unless there is $A \vee \neg A$ in every clause.

This is probably what [Kyle Jones](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/139938/a-conjunctive-normal-form-that-is-a-tautology#comment293746_139938) stated in his comment.

Comment: Do you mean we can assign 0 to a negated variable and 1 to a non-negated variable?

Comment: @Roofnos The statement is a bit confusing. Consider the following statement instead. If a variable $A$ appears in non-negated form, i.e., $A$, we assign $A \gets 0$. If a variable $A$ appears in negated form, i.e., $\neg A$, we assign $A \gets 1$. This makes the clause $0$.